# word-wrap messes the position of the element

Tags: css

I have a problem with CSS word-wrap, it messes up the position of the button according to the number of words it contain as shown below

my css:

```
.btn-small {
width: 14.6%;
height: 100px;
font-size: 13px;
word-wrap: break-word;
margin: 0;
}
```

I am working on chrome,

What should i add in order to control their position better?

[image]

What should I add in order to control their position better?

Comment: Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? Also, try adding `display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;`

Comment: @Vucko `vertical-align:top;` worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `vertical-align:top` that applies to *inline-level and table-cell elements*.

More about [vertical-aling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property.